# Pulling data from AngularJS $http request

Tags: php, angularjs, response

I sending a request to my php file to get data from database from my AngularJS file. Some-time I am getting data also lot of time there is no response is coming.
Here is my AngularJS code:

```
myApp.controller('PageCtrl', function PageCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.post(APP_URL + "server/FullDesc.php", {id: parseInt($routeParams.Id)}).success(function (data) {
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.Details = data[0];
        console.log(data);            
        $scope.$apply($scope.Details);
    }, 10);
  }, 'json');
})
```

In resposne I am getting  [output of my response like this](http://postimg.org/image/46eald25b/)

In image you can see there is no response showing. How to solve this issue.

Comment: Why did you the response handler it in a setTimeout ? $http.success() will wait for a response.

Comment: Check the request to make sure it's being sent properly. If it is, the problem is likely in the PHP code (does it handle id values like 'undefined')?

Comment: Try to test out the api calls using Postman (using the parameters that you are passing) to ensure that you are getting data returned. It's likely that your PHP api call is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding an error scenario as well:

```
myApp.controller('PageCtrl', function PageCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

    $http.post(APP_URL + "server/FullDesc.php", 
        {id: parseInt($routeParams.Id)}
    ).then(function(successResponse){

        var data = successResponse.data;
        console.log('successResponse', data);
        $scope.Details = data[0];

        //$scope.$apply($scope.Details); // assigning to scope should automatically do an apply

    }, function(errorResponse){

        console.log('errorResponse', errorResponse);

    });

});
```

Then you should also check what is being sent to the server and what the server sends back. It seems your server may be encountering an error and you are not sending an error response back.